# Sqlalchemy+elixir: How query with a ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

I'm using sqlalchemy with Elixir and have some troubles trying to make a query..

I have 2 entities, Customer and CustomerList, with a many to many relationship.

```
customer_lists_customers_table = Table('customer_lists_customers', 
                      metadata,
                      Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                      Column('customer_list_id', Integer, ForeignKey("customer_lists.id")),
                      Column('customer_id', Integer, ForeignKey("customers.id")))

class Customer(Entity):
  [...]
  customer_lists = ManyToMany('CustomerList', table=customer_lists_customers_table)

class CustomerList(Entity):
  [...]

  customers = ManyToMany('Customer', table=customer_lists_customers_table)
```

I'm tryng to find CustomerList with some customer:

```
customer = [...]
CustomerList.query.filter_by(customers.contains(customer)).all()
```

But I get the error: 
NameError:

> global name 'customers' is not defined

customers seems to be unrelated to the entity fields, there's an special query form to work with relationships (or ManyToMany relationships)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular filter: `query.filter(CustomerList.customers.contains(customer))`. See SQLAlchemy documentation for more examples. It's actually filter_by that's a special case. The `query.filter_by(**kwargs)` shorthand works only for simple equality comparisons. Under the cover `query.filter_by(foo="bar", baz=42)` is delegated to the equivalent of `query.filter(and_(MyClass.foo == "bar", MyClass.baz == 42))`. (There's actually slightly more magic to figure out which property you meant you have many entities, but it still uses simple delegation)

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message with attention, it points to the source of problem. Did you mean
`CustomerList.query.filter_by(CustomerList.customers.contains(customer)).all()`?

**Update**: When using declarative definition you can use just defined relation in *class* scope, but these properties are not visible outside class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    prop1 = 'somevalue'
    prop2 = prop1.upper() # prop1 is visible here

val2 = MyClass.prop1 # This is OK    

val1 = prop1.lower() # And this will raise NameError, since there is no 
                     # variable `prop1` is global scope
```

Comment: Yes, of course. I understand that, but why it happens? I can use
fields without Entity in all other cases.

Answer (score 0):

`CustomerList.query.filter_by(CustomerList.customers.contains(customer)).all()` should work fine.