# SQLAlchemy/Elixir - querying to check entity's membership in a many-to-many relationship list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, python-elixir

I am trying to construct a sqlalchemy query to get the list of names of all professors who are assistants professors on MIT. Note that there can be multiple assistant professors associated with a certain course.

What I'm trying to do is roughly equivalent to:

```
uni_mit = University.get_by(name='MIT')
s = select([Professor.name],
           and_(Professor.in_(Course.assistants),
                Course.university = uni_mit))
session.execute(s)
```

This won't work, because `in_` is only defined for entity's fields, not for the whole entity.. Can't use `Professor.id.in_` as Course.assistants is a list of Professors, not a list of their ids. I also tried `contains` but I didn't work either.

My Elixir model is:

```
class Course(Entity):
    id = Field(Integer, primary_key=True)
    assistants = ManyToMany('Professor', inverse='courses_assisted', ondelete='cascade')
    university = ManyToOne('University')
    ..

class Professor(Entity):
    id = Field(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Field(String(50), required=True)
    courses_assisted = ManyToMany('Course', inverse='assistants', ondelete='cascade')
    ..
```

This would be trivial if I could access the intermediate many-to-many entity (the condition would be `and_(interm_table.prof_id = Professor.id, interm_table.course = Course.id)`, but SQLAlchemy apparently hides this table from me.

I'm using Elixir 0.7 and SQLAlchemy 0.6.

Btw: This question is different from [Sqlalchemy+elixir: How query with a ManyToMany relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810534/sqlalchemyelixir-how-query-with-a-manytomany-relationship) in that I need to check the professors against all courses which satisfy a condition, not a single, static one.

Comment: It's not sqlalchemy that hides the secondary table; in vanilla sqlalchemy you are *required* to name and describe that table, but are advised not to map it to a class.  The obfuscation occurs due to Elixir.

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the intermediate table where Elixir has hidden it away, but note that it uses fully qualified column names (such as `__package_path_with_underscores__course_id`). To avoid this, define your ManyToMany using e.g.

```
class Course(Entity):
    ...
    assistants = ManyToMany('Professor', inverse='courses_assisted',
                            local_colname='course_id', remote_colname='prof_id',
                            ondelete='cascade')
```

and then you can access the intermediate table using

```
rel = Course._descriptor.find_relationship('assistants')
assert rel
table = rel.table
```

and can access the columns using `table.c.prof_id`, etc.

**Update:** Of course you can do this at a higher level, but not in a single query, because SQLAlchemy doesn't yet support `in_` for relationships. For example, with two queries:

```
>>> mit_courses = set(Course.query.join(
... University).filter(University.name == 'MIT'))
>>> [p.name for p in Professor.query if set(
... p.courses_assisted).intersection(mit_courses)]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
>>> plist = [c.assistants for c in Course.query.join(
... University).filter(University.name == 'MIT')]
>>> [p.name for p in set(itertools.chain(*plist))]
```

The first step creates a list of lists of assistants. The second step flattens the list of lists and removes duplicates through making a set.

Comment: Thank you! With that the solution is going to be straightforward but somewhat long and verbose. Is there a way of approaching this problem without accessing the intermediate table (e.g. some kind of `contains` / `in_` syntax I'm not aware of)? After all, ORMs are intended to abstract from the way the data is stored..